# Server architecture / security for file server

Tags: server, duplicates, scale, fileserver

suppose I have the following server / software architecture for my application:

- Server serves mainly as file server. Security by obscurity is achieved by putting the data into folders like /[random A-Z0-9]/mydata001.zip.
- Clients requests data over a REST API. The send their secret token (access rights checked against database) and tags of desired data.
- Server responses with JSON containing URL to the zip files for the requested data.
- The Client now can download the data over plain HTTP.

So the main load comes from the downloads, right? How can I scale such an architecture to say three servers? Only be duplicating the data?

Thanks for some advice.

Comment: I forgot to mention. the data ist not static. It is updated in intervalls from 5 to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If security is a concern, then at least use HTTPS for the authentication. When the files need to be stored on multiple servers without duplicating the data I can think of several options:

1. Store the files for a specific user always on the same server. This means each user profile contains the server where its files are stored. This only works when there are a lot of users in order to distribute the files evenly.
2. Randomly store the file on one of the file servers and save the file location in the database.

Comment: Thx, HTTPS for the authentication is a good point. For securing the data this random URI seems to be common practice (like Dropbox link, ...).